# Smallest (code-wise) bit - banged serial interface on PIC10

Tags: pic, uart, i2c, spi

I need to interface to a PIC10 micro with some serial interface. Since these small devices lack hardware support for SPI I2C and UART a Software solution is inevitable.

However, since I need to preserve as much of the Programm memory to store (static) configuration and identify information to be retrieved via said interface, what would probably be the smallest solution?

I will need to program this in ASM since there seems no good C compiler for PIC10. However, this will be my first real encounter with ASM to speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this download](http://www.embeddedcodesource.com/developer/datadog_systems/software_uart/download) which contains code samples and says:

"Listed below are five PIC UART software routines to use with PIC microprocessors that have no hardware UART"

Link rot has broken the original link try [this link](http://www.embeddedcodesource.com/codesnippet/software-uart-1).

Comment: There is an issue with the www.embeddedcodesource.com server. The content can also be found [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXmKaSw75eKdjI2elFsWW5Rd28/view)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the xc8 compiler works pretty well, also for the PIC10.
Here is an example in C:

```
#include <xc.h>
#ifndef _XTAL_FREQ
    #define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#endif

#define Baudrate 1200 //bps
#define OneBitDelay (1000000/Baudrate)
#define DataBitCount 8 // no parity, no flow control
#define UART_RX RA1 // UART RX pin
#define UART_TX RA0 // UART TX pin
#define UART_RX_DIR TRISA1 // UART RX pin direction register
#define UART_TX_DIR TRISA0 // UART TX pin direction register

//Function Declarations
void InitSoftUART(void);
unsigned char UART_Receive(void);
void UART_Transmit(const char);

__CONFIG(FOSC_INTOSC & MCLRE_OFF & WDTE_OFF & LVP_OFF & CP_OFF &
         WRT_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & WRT_OFF & BOREN_ON & LPBOR_ON & BORV_LO);

void main()
{ 
 unsigned char ch = 0;

 ANSELA = 0x00; // Set ports as digital I/O, not analog input
 ADCON = 0x00; // Shut off the A/D Converter
 FVRCON = 0x00; // Shut off the Voltage Reference
 PORTA = 0x00; // Make all pins 0

 InitSoftUART(); // Intialize Soft UART

 InitSoftUART(); // Intialize Soft UART

 while(1)
 {
  ch = UART_Receive(); // Receive a character from UART
  UART_Transmit(ch); // Echo back that character
 }
}


void InitSoftUART(void) // Initialize UART pins to proper values
{
 UART_TX = 1; // TX pin is high in idle state

 UART_RX_DIR = 1; // Input
 UART_TX_DIR = 0; // Output
}

unsigned char UART_Receive(void)
{
 // Pin Configurations
    // GP1 is UART RX Pin

 unsigned char DataValue = 0;

 //wait for start bit
 while(UART_RX==1);

 __delay_us(OneBitDelay);
 __delay_us(OneBitDelay/2); // Take sample value in the mid of bit duration

 for ( unsigned char i = 0; i < DataBitCount; i++ )
 {
  if ( UART_RX == 1 ) //if received bit is high
  {
   DataValue += (1<<i);
  }

  __delay_us(OneBitDelay);
 }

 // Check for stop bit
 if ( UART_RX == 1 ) //Stop bit should be high
 {
  __delay_us(OneBitDelay/2);
  return DataValue;
 }
 else //some error occurred !
 {
  __delay_us(OneBitDelay/2);
  return 0x000;
 }
}

void UART_Transmit(const char DataValue)
{
 /* Basic Logic

    TX pin is usually high. A high to low bit is the starting bit and 
    a low to high bit is the ending bit. No parity bit. No flow control.
    BitCount is the number of bits to transmit. Data is transmitted LSB first.

 */

 // Send Start Bit
 UART_TX = 0;
 __delay_us(OneBitDelay);

 for ( unsigned char i = 0; i < DataBitCount; i++ )
 {
  //Set Data pin according to the DataValue
  if( ((DataValue>>i)&0x1) == 0x1 ) //if Bit is high
  {
   UART_TX = 1;
  }
  else //if Bit is low
  {
   UART_TX = 0;
  }

     __delay_us(OneBitDelay);
 }

 //Send Stop Bit
 UART_TX = 1;
 __delay_us(OneBitDelay);
}
```

Source for this code is the :[Microchip forum](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m926980.aspx)